# Where is old LinkedIn REST API documentation

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

I was using LinkedIn REST API. Everithing was ok, but now I need to improve app and I can't find proper documentation. Where is it? Actual documentation is totally shitty. I want documentation where all fields will be described clearly etc. Especially I need documentation for GROUPS, but I can't google it. Where is it? Thanks.

Comment: seems to be restricted now: https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes; somebody let the marketing department run with those pages; more here https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are the old docs: https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/

I agree, the new docs are absolute garbage.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. For some reason I just kept clicking around the new docs hoping to find something useful. Not sure why I waited this long, but you pointed me to exactly where I needed to be. Thanks

Comment: What are these folks smoking.  Makes me wonder.  Or might it be a precursor to closing of the api - might be smart to plan move away from them....

Comment: this link is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

Archive.org has a copy here
https://web.archive.org/web/20150426071159/http://developer-programs.linkedin.com:80/

after 2015-04-26 it appears the viewing the documentation required sign-in and the usefulness of the copy on archive.org deteriorates.